# Is a SCSS able to detect if a fallback font is used

Tags: sass, mixins

I'm not sure how to word this, but if I've got something like the following variables:

```
$font-light: ("ford_antennalight", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif);
$font-regular: ("ford_antennaregular", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif);
$font-bold: ("ford_antennabold", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif);
```

The ford fonts should only be displayed at a normal font weight. Whereas, if the fallback fonts are used they should use something like font-weight: 300, font-weight: 500 and font-weight: 700 accordingly.

Is it possible to set something like that up in a mixin. IE. If any of the ford fonts are used set the font-weight: normal, else set the font weight accordingly.

Hope that makes some sort of sense. 
Thanks.